# AFNetworking 2.0 POST request not working

Tags: ios7, afnetworking, http-post

I am trying to make a POST request using AFNetworking 2.0.
This is the code

```
NSMutableDictionary *params=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setValue:@"iOS" forKey:@"device"];
[params setValue:@"" forKey:@"token"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:ServerURL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

}

failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
```

I have followed many question and they all have done something similar to what i have done above . I do not understand what i am missing. i get a valid response using the old Afnetworking library.

The error i get is

{ status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 195;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 21 Apr 2014 06:53:55 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.25 (Amazon)";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.27";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html}

Comment: This is not error. 200 means all is well. try to log operation.responseObject or operation.responseData.

Comment: Yes i understand. But then y is the failure block called? The above response is the error NSlog

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

not sure if this is the right way , but it worked for me

Cheers.